# Google Analytics tracking a page hosted in a Google Drive public folder

Tags: google-analytics, google-drive-api

I have included a Universal Analytics tracking code in a html page, hosted in a public folder in Google Drive.

The page is working fine, however I don't see any trace of that page under Behavior - Overview reporting in Google Analytics.

Am I missing something basic or there is some limitation in Google Drive I am not aware of?

This is a fragment of the code

```
// some other script ending here...
</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'mydomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview','/mappingHtml');
</script>

</html>
```

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is unclear but in the [ga Object Methods for create](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#create) you can set the trackingId as auto e.g.

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'auto');
```

This should enable tracking (alternatively for Google Drive hosted content using `ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'googledrive.com');` also appears to work

Comment: Just wondering if this worked? Usually, you can't track pages outside your domain. Thanks,